# Compile assembly program in SASM IDE

Tags: assembly, nasm

The SASM IDE is a crosplatform IDE with NASM support. It provides debugging functions to observe the registers during the execution of the program. The following code compiles with NASM without any issue.

```
    section .data
hello   db "Hello World!",0xa
len equ $-hello

    section .text
    global  _start

_start:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, hello
    mov edx, len
    int 80h

    mov eax, 1 ; exit(0)
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

But if you try to execute the same code in the SASM IDE it doesn't work. Here the complete error message.

[14:46:07] Warning! Errors have occurred in the build:
/tmp/SASM/program.o:/tmp/SASM/program.asm:9: multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function`_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
[14:46:07] Before debugging you need to build the program.

Because it doesn't work I guess there must be a difference between the SASM IDE and NASM (Usually I thought SASM is more or less just a GUI for NASM).

What must be fulfilled to compile the program in SASM ?

Comment: SASM seems to say you should use `CMAIN` macro for entry point, not `_start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it works with the following modifications. (include in the first line and change _start to CMAIN)

```
%include "io64.inc"

      section .data
hello   db "Hello World!",0xa
len equ $-hello

    section .text
    global  CMAIN

CMAIN:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, hello
    mov edx, len
    int 80h

    mov eax, 1 ; exit(0)
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

But for me the more important question is, what's the difference between SASM and NASM ? In my opinion that's not a NASM Support anymore because native NASM programs are not executable without modifications. Or are there settings to execute such programs ?

Comment: It's still `nasm` code, the difference is in linking. Apparently `sasm` links with the C library (you might be able to turn this off somewhere).

Comment: You are right. In settings you can change the assembly options and the linker options. Type for assembly options: "-f elf64 $SOURCE$" and for Linking options "-o $PROGRAM$ $PROGRAM.OBJ$" and it will compile.